# avoid any emailPrefix with git-multimail

Tags: git, githooks

Is there a way to avoid any email prefix while using the git-multimail script ?

I use mailman which already prefix any message, so I don't need that the git-multimail script does it for me.

If I set an empty multimailhook.emailprefix, it is the same behaviour than if config unset, says it use the repo name as prefix.

thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why people downvote this question without adding a comment. It really does not help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wasn't possible until a minute ago, when I just pushed [a change to `git-multimail`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-multimail/commit/6d81fc79319d280973fb55d12efe96cf264aa9b5) that makes

```
git config multimailhook.emailprefix ""
```

suppress the email prefix.  Hope that helps!